# Count rows with "x" in at least one of the previous 4 cells

Tags: excel-formula, subtotal

I want to count the number of rows by Region (D1) and Manager (F1) which have at least one X in the previous 4 cells from specified Month (B1). Here is the code I have been able to put together but it only adds all the X's in the specified rows. Data table is in Data Sheet, the formula and parameters (B1,D1,F1) are in separate sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Data!$A$3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MATCH("zzz",Data!$A:$A)-3)),MATCH(B1,Data!$3:$3,0)-1,1,-4))*(Data!$A$4:INDEX(Data!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Data!$A:$A))=D1)*(Data!$A$4:INDEX(Data!$B:$B,MATCH("zzz",Data!$B:$B))=F1))
```

[image: Data Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula works for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$4:$A$99=D1)*(Data!$B$4:$B$99=F1)*
 (0<COUNTIF(OFFSET(Data!$A$1,ROW($4:$99)-1,MATCH(B1,Data!$3:$3,0)-5,1,4),"x")))
```